# Why is there a seemingly identical copy of the JDK 1.5 core runtime in org.osgi.foundation-1.0.0.jar?

Tags: web-applications, jboss, osgi, apache-felix

I am maintaining a web application that depends on OSGi and Maven pulls in a jar called `org.osgi-foundation-1.0.0.jar` that seems to contain the same classes as part of the JDK core runtime such as:

```
java.util.\*;
java.io.\*;
```

etc. and so on.

This seems very strange and I have to ask why this is necessary.  More-over, my web-application fails to deploy on JBoss 6 because these are "illegal package names" for a third-party library.

What is the purpose of `org.osgi-foundation-1.0.0.jar`? Is it necessary?

Comment: Google reveals that this jar seems to be [specific to Apache Felix](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.felix/org.osgi.foundation/1.0.0). You should check from where it gets pulled in. Ideally, your application should not depend on a specific OSGi framework. Make your application depend on [`org.osgi:org.osgi.core`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.osgi/org.osgi.core) etc. instead.

Comment: See other answers ... foundation is an execution environment to ensure you do not accidentally compile against the wrong jdk. This is mainly relevant for embedded and people that want to run on lower version VMs than their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.osgi.foundation` is a bundle containing all classes in the Foundation execution environment (see section 999 of the OSGi Compendium Specification).

In short, an execution environment is the set of classes that are supposed to be available from the framework. They are grouped in profiles, such as `JavaME` or `OSGi/Minimum`. Bundles can express their use of a given execution environment in their manifest, and make sure they will only be started on a platform that e.g. provides AWT.

The `org.osgi.foundation` bundle you found represents one of these environments. It contains only stub classes, and is therefore only to be used during compilation.

So, if Maven pulls in the bundle as a compile dependency, that's fine, but it should never be deployed alongside your application.

Comment: It is an execution environment. See section 999 of the Compendium Specification. It contains stub classes (no method bodies). You can compile against it but it cannot be used at runtime. So it should only be a compile time dependency replacing the normal javac bootclasspath.

Comment: I missed the Compendium section 999 reference, thanks! I'll update my answer for that.